# What does the Life Medal do?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Beedle is selling an item with the name **Life Medal**. Beedle has no idea what it does, but he's selling it for 800 rupees, which is quite a bit of rupees.

What does the Life Medal do?

Comment: Making money becomes pretty easy once you are able to go to `Fun Fun Island`, but that's quite a ways off though from your point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this wiki](http://ie.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/Life_Medal):

> The Life Medal adds a single Heart Container to your life bar at the expense of an Adventure Pouch space.